# proving the big-oh etc for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm learning how to prove/disprove big-Oh, big-Omega, and little-oh, and I have the following algorithm f(n). However I'm unsure how to prove this f(n) as it has an if statement which I've never come across before. How can I prove, for example, that this f(n) is O( n^2 )?

```
if n is even
  4 sum(n/2,n)
else
  2n-1 sum(n−3,n)
```

where sum(j,k) is a ‘partial arithmetic sum’ of the integers from j up to k, that is sum(j,k)=

```
if j > k
   0
else
   j+(j+1)+(j+2)+...+j
```

e.g. sum(3,4) = 3 + 4 = 7, etc.
Note that sum(j,k) = sum(1,k) – sum(1,j-1).

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri that was not my question...

Comment: Can you please help me understand how "4" & "sum(n/2,n)" are associated? Is it multiplication/summation of both?

Comment: @AmitKumar It's multiplication, so you'd get the sum(n/2,n) and then multiply this by 4.

Comment: How are you accomplishing the magical `...` operation in your implementation of `sum`?  Looping?  Recursion?  Closed form formula equivalent?

Comment: @pjs in a loop, it just sums the integers from  up to 

Comment: @AmitKumar Yes exactly, I'm just unsure how i would prove the big oh of such a function, i've never come across one which has an if else :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. Got it no worries. I'll try to help you understand this.

Big O notation is used to define an upper limit on how much time a program will take in term of its input size.

Let's try to see how much time each statement will take in this function

```
f(n) {
  if n is even     // O(1) .....#1
    4 * sum(n/2,n) // O(n) .....#2
  else  // O(1) ................#3
    (2n-1) * sum(n−3,n) // O(n) .......#4
}
```

`if n is even`
This can be done by a check like `if ((n%2) == 0))` As you can see that this is a constant time operation. no loop nothing just one computation.

`sum(j, k)` function is being computated by iterating from `j` to `k` whenever `j <= k`. So, it will run `(k - j + 1)` times which is linear time

So, total complexity will be summation of complexity of the `if` block or the `else` block
For analyzing complexity, one needs to take care of worst time.
Complexity of `if` block = `#1 + #2 = O(1) + O(n)` = `O(n)`

Similarly for `else` block = `#3 + #4 = O(1) + O(n)` = `O(n)`
Max of both = `maximum of(O(n), O(n)) = O(n)`

Thus, the overall complexity = O(n)